# Run code every 2 days

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, action

I'm making this project https://www.hackster.io/demirhanaydin/waterpi-houseplant-remote-watering-and-monitoring-system-340400 and need help running this line of code every 2 days. On that website the creator says to just add the right parameters to run it periodically. Im not sure what parameters to use. I added the every 1.day to my code and now I get a run time error.

```
CLIENT.publish('pump/data', {state:{pump: params['action']}}.to_json)
```

Here is the entire ruby app

```
    # app.rb
    require 'sinatra'
    require './boot'




    set :sessions, true
    set :session_secret, SESSION_SECRET

    enable :sessions



    get '/' do
      haml 'welcome/index'.to_sym
    end
    every (every 1.day, :at => '08:30') do
CLIENT.publish('pump/data', {state:{pump: params['action']}}.to_json)
end

    post '/take-action' do
      CLIENT.publish('pump/data', {state:{pump: params['action']}}.to_json)
      200
      end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We do not go somewhere else to look at information in order to figure out what you're asking. Please spend a few minutes taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, especially [ask], and then come back and [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Periodically Run Ruby COde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49165214/periodically-run-ruby-code)

Comment: take a look at the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem

Comment: @maxpleaner is that the same as clockwork? I just found that gem

Comment: @taylordudley not the same but either one works

Comment: @maxpleaner neither of them work

Comment: @taylordudley the gems clearly do work ... tons of people are using them. It's not productive to just say "they don't work", if you're having an issue and need help with it, you can include it in your question.

Comment: @maxpleaner thats not what I meant, I have the gems included and I know the gems work I think its my syntax